# Regular Expression to get a string between parentheses and inside the string literal in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

```
let s =  "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `product_categories` (`id`))"
```

here I need to extract the FOREIGN key inside the literal with parenthesis ex. `extracted = "category_id"`. I don't know how to do with
`regexp`.

Anyone, can you help me?

Thank in advance for your great community support.

Comment: Look into capture groups

Comment: Do you want all occurrences between backticks, or just the foreign-key name?

Comment: Just foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let s =  "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`products`, CONSTRAINT `products_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `product_categories` (`id`))";

let match = /FOREIGN KEY \(`([\w]*)`\)/.exec(s);
let extracted = match[1];
console.log(extracted);
```

**Edit:**

The pattern(`/FOREIGN KEY (([\w]*))/`) does extract "FOREIGN KEY (category_id)" and "category_id" from string. Please refer to [this url](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-regular-expression/).